# convert time to different time zones in lightning

Tags: lightning

I am selecting a dateTime from a lightning:input type=dateTime. 
I need to format the time in hh:mm:ss am/pm for the time zone : **(GMT -4:00)Eastern DayLight Time(America/Newyork)**.
**Is it possible to have Time converted to different timezones also?**

Here is what I have done.

```
<lightning:input type="dateTime" aura:id="dateTime" label="date and time" name="date">
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="submit" onclick="{!c.makeASubmit}"/>
```

---

```
({ makeASubmit:componewnt : function(component,event,helper)
 var dateTime = component.find("dateTime").get("v.value");
 alert("GMT...'+dateTime);
 var dateTime1=$A.localizationService.formatDate(dateTime,"MM/DD/YYYY, hh:mm:ss a");
})
```

If I select April 16th, 10:00 AM , then after localization I get a dateTime as  04/16/2020 7:30:00 PM
so it is effectively taking my laptop time which I need to avoid. It should take the time as per the time zone specified above.
Pls help me out.

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your code. You can use the `{}` tool or wrap each code block separately in triple backticks (```).

Comment: Why do you need the time in a different time zone?

Comment: @sfdcfox, I am working for a health insurance client where in the operators are located in states like newyork,arizona, london to provide health insurance. Its not mandatory for me to have time in different timezones but only for the timezone specified in the question..

Comment: Is this only for display purposes, though? lightning:formattedDateTime would work just fine for this purpose.

Comment: Yes,they are displaying the dateTime in the pageLayout. Business wants to have the lightning:input type=dateTime, if I go with lighthing:formattedDateTime then there would be a major UI change.Also they would like a to enter a date followed with time